# Powershell folder size of folders without listing Subdirectories

Tags: powershell

I have found several resources that use the following script to get folder sizes

```
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

The problem with that is it also lists the subdirectories ie:

```
c:\test\1 -- 10mb
c:\test\1\folder -- 10mb
c:\test\1\folder\deep -- 5mb
c:\test\1\folder\tuna -- 5mb
c:\test\2 -- 20bm
c:\test\2\folder -- 20mb
c:\test\2\folder\deep -- 10mb
c:\test\2\folder\tuna -- 10mb
```

I think you know see where I am going.  What I am looking for is just the parent folder's results...  SO:

```
c:\test\1 -- 10mb
c:\test\2 -- 20mb
```

How can this be accomplished with Powershell?
    ....

Comment: Have a look at [Hey, Scripting Guy! Getting Directory Sizes in PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell.aspx). The Get-DirStats.ps1 script referenced there does what you are asking by default.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2013/05/getting-top-level-folder-report-in-powershell/.

Comment: If `$startFolder` is `c:\test` could you not just remove the `-recurse`?

Comment: FYI, Get-ChildItem will not list any files or folders that are hidden unless you use the -Force parameter.

Comment: If I remove it does not calculate for the subdirectories

Comment: The update is a different question than the original (using output from a script/command in another script/command), and warrants it's own question submission rather than an add-on to this one.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to get the total contents size of each directory recursively to output. Also, you need to specify that the contents you're grabbing to measure are not directories, or you risk errors (as directories do not have a `Length` parameter).

Here's your script modified for the output you're looking for:

```
$colItems = Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
}
```

Comment: If I remove it does not calculate for the subdirectories

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.  SO I am kind of new to stackoverflow, was it wrong to update my original question with what I thought was the answer?

Comment: [Answering your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) is OK. However, you should have posted it as an answer instead of an update.

Comment: but it was a partial answer, still incomplete.   No worries I am going to remove my edit.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Calculation is not accurate. -1

Comment: Nowadays, `Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer …}` can be simplified by `Get-ChildItem -Directory` and `Get-ChildItem -File`.

Answer (score 23):

This simple solution worked for me as well.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'directory_path' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This shows how many items are in the directory and the sum of bytes the directory is.

Answer (score 9):

The solution posted by @Linga:
`"Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'directory_path' | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum"` is nice and short. However, it only computes the size of `'directory_path'`, without sub-directories.
Here is a simple solution for listing all sub-directory sizes. With a little pretty-printing added.
(Note: use the `-File` option to avoid errors for empty sub-directories)

```
foreach ($d in gci -Directory -Force) {
  '{0,15:N0}' -f ((gci $d -File -Recurse -Force | measure length -sum).sum) + "`t`t$d" 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to reanimate a dead thread, but I have just been dealing with this myself, and after finding all sorts of crazy bloated solutions, I managed to come up with this.

```
[Long]$actualSize = 0
foreach ($item in (Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Where {-not $_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {$_.FullName})) {
   $actualSize += (Get-Item $item).length
}
```

Quickly and in few lines of code gives me a folder size in Bytes, than can easily be converted to any units you want with `/ 1MB` or the like.
Am I missing something? Compared to this [overwrought mess](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/25/getting-directory-sizes-in-powershell/) it seems rather simple and to the point. Not to mention that code doesn't even work since the called function is not the same name as the defined function. And has been wrong for 6 years. ;)
So, any reasons NOT to use this stripped down approach?

Comment: works a treat for me, though [long] is too short :). long is about 19 significant digits which I think is about 10 exabytes.
Replace with [decimal] gives you 28 significant digits and it takes about the same time to calculate

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could future proof the code at the expense of a little more memory use. But I suspect 10EB should good for a while. ;)

Comment: This breaks if there is a subdirectory that occurs before .svn -- like .idea.  Get duplication then.

Comment: @rojs, can you elaborate? Not sure I am following.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396598/kohlbrr answer, but I was trying to get the total size of a single folder and found that the script doesn't count the files in the Root of the folder you are searching. This worked for me.

```
$startFolder = "C:\Users";
$totalSize = 0;

$colItems = Get-ChildItem $startFolder
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $totalSize = $totalSize + $subFolderItems.sum / 1MB

}

$startFolder + " | " + "{0:N2}" -f ($totalSize) + " MB"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something I wind up looking for repeatedly, even though I wrote myself a nice little function a while ago.  So, I figured others might benefit from having it and maybe I'll even find it here, myself.  hahaha

It's pretty simple to paste into your script and use.  Just pass it a folder object.

I think it requires PowerShell 3 just because of the -directory flag on the Get-ChildItem command, but I'm sure it can be easily adapted, if need be.

```
function Get-TreeSize ($folder = $null)
{
    #Function to get recursive folder size
    $result = @()
    $folderResult = "" | Select-Object FolderPath, FolderName, SizeKB, SizeMB, SizeGB, OverThreshold

    $contents  = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -recurse -force -erroraction SilentlyContinue -Include * | Where-Object {$_.psiscontainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -Property length -sum | Select-Object sum
    $sizeKB = [math]::Round($contents.sum / 1000,3)   #.ToString("#.##")
    $sizeMB = [math]::Round($contents.sum / 1000000,3)   #.ToString("#.##")
    $sizeGB = [math]::Round($contents.sum / 1000000000,3)   #.ToString("#.###")

    $folderResult.FolderPath = $folder.FullName
    $folderResult.FolderName = $folder.BaseName
    $folderResult.SizeKB = $sizeKB
    $folderresult.SizeMB = $sizeMB
    $folderresult.SizeGB = $sizeGB
    $result += $folderResult

    return $result
} 


#Use the function like this for a single directory
$topDir = get-item "C:\test"
Get-TreeSize ($topDir)

#Use the function like this for all top level folders within a direcotry
#$topDir = gci -directory "\\server\share\folder"
$topDir = Get-ChildItem -directory "C:\test"
foreach ($folderPath in $topDir) {Get-TreeSize $folderPath}
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

```
$dir="C:\temp\"
get-childitem $dir -file -Rec | group Directory | where Name -eq $dir | select Name, @{N='Size';E={(($_.Group.Length | measure -Sum).Sum / 1MB)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

from sysinternals.com with du.exe or du64.exe -l 1 .
or 2 levels down:
**du -l 2 c:**

Much shorter than Linux though ;)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! To make your answer even more useful to others, consider adding some more details, such as a link to where this du.exe can be downloaded exactly, and maybe a PowerShell example on how to use it (ideally similar to the original script in the question). See also [this post on writing good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

At the answer from `@squicc` if you `amend` this line: `$topDir = Get-ChildItem -directory "C:\test" with -force` then you will be able to see the hidden directories also. Without this, the size will be different when you run the solution from inside or outside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I used the great answer of @kohlbrr and improved it a bit. I also turned it into a function you can put in your `$PROFILE`. This outputs three properties instead of just text: `Name`, `Size` (which is a string output of the size converted to MB), and `Value` which is the raw size value you can use with `| sort value`

```
function Get-DirectorySize([string] $rootFolder) {
  $colItems = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
  
  foreach ($i in $colItems) {
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name=$i.Fullname; Size="{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"; Value=$subFolderItems.sum }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script provides file sizes from a directory(not going deep) and sizes in bytes.(give your path in $($args[0]) in both the scripts)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($args[0])" -Recurse -Depth 0 -file| select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Export-Csv .\FileAndFolderSizes.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The following script provides the folder sizes(depth 0 ) in bytes within the given directory.

```
$array= @()
Get-ChildItem -Path "$($args[0])" -Recurse -Depth 0 | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
ForEach-Object {
$obj = New-Object PSObject

$Size = [Math]::Round((Get-ChildItem -Recurse $_.FullName | Measure-Object Length -Sum -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Sum, 2)
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FullName" $_.FullName
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LastWriteTime" $_.LastWriteTime
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Length" $Size
$array +=$obj
}
$array | select Length,LastWriteTime,FullName | Export-Csv .\FileAndFolderSizes.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Output is as follows

```
"Length","LastWriteTime","FullName"
"593408","2/17/2022 10:51:01 PM","C:\a_appli\Partners_Ref\Client64_Rws2\compresslayer.dll"
"286720","2/9/2021 11:52:18 PM","C:\a_appli\Partners_Ref\Client64_Rws2\fdsrtd.dll"
"589312","6/19/2019 10:18:41 PM","C:\a_appli\Partners_Ref\Client64_Rws2\FdswCli.dll"
"13658276","3/18/2022 9:52:16 AM","C:\a_appli\Partners_Ref\Client64_Rws2\PartnersTemplateBuilder"
```

Answer (score -5):

Interesting how powerful yet how helpless PS can be in the same time, coming from a Nix learning PS. after install crgwin/gitbash, you can do any combination in one commands:

size of current folder:
du -sk .

size of all files and folders under current directory
du -sk *

size of all subfolders (including current folders)
find ./ -type d -exec du -sk {} \;