# How to recursively get the size of all files and folders in PowerShell, custom output

Tags: powershell, recursion, file-io

I want to get the size of each files/folders in a specific path and output it in a file.

I played with PowerShell as far as I could with my very limited PowerShell knowledge and look through many posts yet I can't seem to find a way to output it as I need it.

Currently, I have the below script, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494744/powershell-folder-size-of-folders-without-listing-subdirectories).

```
$folderToBeListed = "PATH";
$folder = (Get-ChildItem $folderToBeListed -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $False} | Sort-Object)

foreach ($i in $folder)
{
    $i.DirectoryName
    $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum)
    $i.Name + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum /1MB) + " MB"

}

<#
$date = "$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd@HH)h$(Get-Date -f mm)m$(Get-Date -f ss)s"
Out-File PATH\filesSizes_$date.txt
#>
```

This outputs the below format :

```
DirectoryName -- size MB
FileName -- size MB
DirectoryName
FileName -- size MB
```

I would like the output to be like this :

```
DirectoryName -- size MB
    FileName1 -- size MB
    FileName2 -- size MB
    Folder1 -- size MB
        FileName3 -- size MB
        FileName4 -- size MB
    Folder2 -- size MB
        FileName5 -- size MB
DirectoryName2 -- size MB
...
```

Is there a way to go through all the files and folders recursively to format them in such a way or do I have to keep formatting the output with the `DirectoryName` over the file and then filter them by directory name ?

Then I would like to output the result in a file (the commented part is my starting point yet I don't know what to feed the Out-File.

**Update**

The indentation is optional. I put it so it shows more visually what I intend to get as the output but really, the below output would be fine.

```
DirectoryName -- size MB
FileName1 -- size MB
FileName2 -- size MB
Folder1 -- size MB
FileName3 -- size MB
FileName4 -- size MB
Folder2 -- size MB
FileName5 -- size MB
DirectoryName2 -- size MB
...
```

**Update 2**

This is an update of what I currently have. It still has flaws and is not right yet. I will describe the problems with this below the code.

```
$folderToBeListed = "PATH";
$elements = Get-ChildItem $folderToBeListed -recurse
$originSize = getSizeFolder -path $folderToBeListed
"Listed folder : " + $folderToBeListed + " -- Size : " + $originSize + " MB"| Out-String

foreach ($i in $elements)
{
    if($i.PSIsContainer -eq $True)
    {
        try
        {
            $folderSize = getSizeFolder -path $i.FullName

            "`n`nFolder -- " + $i.Name + " -- Size : " + $folderSize + " MB" | Out-String 

            foreach ($it in (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse))
            {
                $fileSize = getSizeFile -path $it.FullName
                $it.Name + " -- " + $fileSize + " KB"
            }

        }
        catch
        {
            "NOOO (It's a catch, line ~28)" | Out-String
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $i.Name + " -- " + $fileSize + " KB"
    }    
}

function getSizeFolder($path)
{
   $sizeFolder = (Get-Item $path).GetFiles() | Measure-Object -Sum Length
   return $sizeFolder.Sum / 1000000 <#Supposed MB#>
}

function getSizeFile($path)
{
    $sizeFile = (Get-Item $path).Length
    return $sizeFile / 1000 <#Supposed KB#>
}
```

Alright so the situations I have encounter yet are the following :

1- If there is a folder containing other folder, it does list every folder and files inside only.

```
Folder -- DirectoryName -- Size XX MB
Folder1 -- Size XX KB
Folder2 -- Size XX KB
FileInFolder1 -- Size XX KB
...
```

2- If there is only folders containing files, it shows it fine.

```
Folder -- DirectoryName -- Size XX MB
File1 -- Size XX KB
File2 -- Size XX KB
Folder2 -- DirectoryName -- Size XX MB
File3 -- Size XX KB
File4 -- Size XX KB
...
```

That being said, I still have all the files listed in the end because of the else clause...

**Update 3**

Took a bit of different approach. This does list all the folders and the files in the chosen folder yet I have no implemented the "recursiveness" yet. Still trying to figure out the algorithm I'll use for it to work. I have also not already started the write operation in a txt file.  All the help is appreciated !

```
function getFoldersInFolder($path)
{
    [array]$elements = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
    return $elements
}

function getFilesInFolder($path)
{
    [array]$elements = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
    return $elements
}

function getSizeFolder($path)
{
   $sizeFolder = (Get-Item $path).GetFiles() | Measure-Object -Sum Length

   if($sizeFolder.Sum -lt 1000)<#Octets#>
   {
        if($sizeFolder.Sum -eq $Null)<#The folder contains only folders#>
        {
            return "`n`nThe size is null (th efolder only contains folders.)`nThe sizes of each folder will be displayed below."
        }
        else
        {
            return "{0:N2}" -f $sizeFolder.Sum + " octets"
        }
   }
   elseif($sizeFolder.Sum -gt 1000 -and $sizeFolder.Sum -lt 999999)<#Ko#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFolder.Sum / 1000) + " Ko"
   }
   elseif($sizeFolder.Sum -gt 1000000 -and $sizeFolder.Sum -lt 999999999)<#Mo#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFolder.Sum / 1000000) + " Mo"
   }
   elseif($sizeFolder.Sum -gt 1000000000 -and $sizeFolder.Sum -lt 999999999999)<#Go#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFolder.Sum / 1000000000) + " Go"     
   }

}

function getSizeFile($path)
{
   $sizeFile = (Get-Item $path).Length

   if($sizeFile -lt 1000)<#Octets#>
   {
        return "{0:N2}" -f $sizeFile + " octets"
   }
   elseif($sizeFile -gt 1000 -and $sizeFile -lt 999999)<#Ko#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFile / 1000) + " Ko"
   }
   elseif($sizeFile -gt 1000000 -and $sizeFile -lt 999999999)<#Mo#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFile / 1000000) + " Mo"
   }
   elseif($sizeFile -gt 1000000000 -and $sizeFile -lt 999999999999)<#Go#>
   {
       return "{0:N2}" -f ($sizeFile / 1000000000) + " Go"     
   }
}

function main()
{
    $folder = "{INPUT PATH HERE}"

    $originFolderSize = getSizeFolder -path $folder

    Write-Host "`nBelow are the files/folders from : $folder => Size : $originFolderSize `n"    

    <#List all folders#>

    [array]$foldersInFolder = getFoldersInFolder -path $folder

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $foldersInFolder.Count; $i++)
    {
        ##$foldersInFolder[$i] | Out-String

        $tempPath = $folder + "\" + $foldersInFolder[$i]

        $tempFolderSize = getSizeFolder -path $tempPath

        Write-Host FOLDER => $foldersInFolder[$i] => Size : $tempFolderSize`n        
    }

    <#List all files#>
    [array]$filesInFolder = getFilesInFolder -path $folder

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $filesInFolder.Count; $i++)
    {
        ##$filesInFolder[$i] | Out-String

        $tempPath = $folder + "\" + $filesInFolder[$i]

        $tempFileSize = getSizeFile -path $tempPath

        Write-Host FILE => $filesInFolder[$i] => Size : $tempFileSize`n
    }

}

main
```

This does outputs like this :

```
Below are the files/folders from : PATH => Size : XX,XX Mo
FOLDER1 => Folder1Name => Size : XX,XX Mo
FOLDER2 => Folder2Name => Size : XX,XX Ko
FILE1 => File1Name => Size : XX,XX Mo
FILE2 => File2Name => Size : XX,XX Go
FILE3 => File3Name => Size : XX,XX Ko
```

Comment: `DirectoryName` and `Folder1` aren't really distinguishable.  You would still end up with the size next to that as well.  It would pretty difficult to get it to be recursive while also auto-indenting like you're doing

Comment: The indentation is not really my focus, it's more about the format where I get the `DirectoryName` on top and then all the files from this specific directory and so on for each of them. It could end up no indentation at all as long as it follows the format

Comment: I have done this in the past. I don't have the time to write out the answer but I will tell you that I used recursion and passed the indentation level into the recursive function the function then increments the indentation before it calls itself.

Comment: Oh, and to make sure that you get the directory then a list of the files in that directory before listing new files, Just always do a Get-ChildItem for just files then do another for further recursion.

Comment: Those are good starting points, I'll look that way ! Thanks @EBGreen

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same but for directories only in a delimited deep level. Also, i need eficience not recalculing subdirectories size yet calculated in a previous recursive iteration. Using many examples finaly i wrote my own solution:

```
powershell -command ".\scriptMida.ps1 -Directory c:\hp -level 2 -HiddeErrors"

Temps#nivell#DirectoryPath#FileSize#FileSize(MB)#FileSize(GB)
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\BIN#347095#0.33#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\bridge#2460#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\bridge#2460#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\browser#78553#0.07#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\BTBHost#715797#0.68#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Favs#6098#0.01#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Netflix#76#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\HPQWare\Simplesolitaire#6#0#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\HPQWare#803076#0.77#0.00
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\McAfeeRules#8014#0.01#0
2022/07/16 01:21#3#C:\hp\support\flexroot#152866#0.15#0
2022/07/16 01:21#2#C:\hp\support#320415#0.31#0.00
```

The code is in github https://github.com/elmeuavi/RecursiveDirSize with examples and with also another "human" presentation and with a secondary script to compare 2 executions of same directories.

It can be easy to you to modify it adding at the output the files of each directory you enter in the recursive function and changing output presentation if you desire.

Answer (score -5):

Look up the these two commands, they might be of use:

```
df

dh
```

Here is an example of getting sizes of things with a max depth of two directories and in human format (not 512 byte blocks)

```
> du -h --max-depth=2
 1.0K    ./.docker
 1.0K    ./.eclipse/org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri
 2.0K    ./.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo
 2.6M    ./.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2
 578K    ./.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup
 1.0K    ./.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer
 3.2M    ./.eclipse
 209M    ./.m2/repository
 209M    ./.m2
 0       ./.matplotlib
 0       ./.nbi/downloads
 5.0M    ./.nbi/log
 364K    ./.nbi/product-cache
 317K    ./.nbi/tmp
 0       ./.nbi/wd
 5.8M    ./.nbi
 109K    ./.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core
 467K    ./.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine
 2.5M    ./.p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository
 203M    ./.p2/pool
 206M    ./.p2
 6.0K    ./.ssh
 68K     ./.tooling/gradle
 68K     ./.tooling
```

This worked on my Win10 PowerShell.  Your success may vary.

Comment: I suspect that you have some windows ports of *nix utils installed

Comment: @EBGreen  I do, but I checked the help/man on it and it seemed to indicate it was part of WinCore...   I guess I was dreaming about Win10 being not being another bit of M$ crapware...  my bad.    I think I have Cygwin (outdated most likely) on this thing somewhere...

Comment: Well, sidestepping the religious war, They don't exist on a straight Win10 box.

Comment: @EBGreen - not taking the bait huh?  Must be the Cygwin then.. :/