# How to get the folder sizes of top folders in shared drive and sort them from bigger to smaller

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using get-childitem command to get the folders inside a shared drive. But when iam using the property length it is returning blank.
How to sort the folder sizes by size using powershell

Command iam using
Get-childitem -path $path -directory -depth 0

I have tried get childitem command.

Comment: Folders don't have a length property. You need to sum up the sizes of all files, e. g. using `Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell folder size of folders without listing Subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494744/powershell-folder-size-of-folders-without-listing-subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a ForEach-Object loop, iterating the top folders in the share like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $size = 0 + (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Directory = $_.Name
        Size = $size
    }
} | Sort-Object Size -Descending
```

Or use calculated properties with a Select-Object cmdlet like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | 
Select-Object @{ Name = 'Directory'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
              @{ Name = 'Size'; Expression = { 
                0 + (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum}
              } | 
Sort-Object Size -Descending
```

<sup>P.S. If you would rather have blanks instead of `0` for folders that do not have files in them, just remove the `0 +`</sup>